# How to assign/declear a structure to a particular address pointed by a pointer?

Tags: c, linux, pointers, memory, mmap

I'm trying to assign a structure to a particular memory type(write-back) location. My ultimate goal is to read from that memory location into L1D cache.

To achieve this, I did the following,

1. Using the sample code from [MTRR (Memory Type Range Register) control](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/x86/mtrr.txt) to declare a memory range as a write-back type.
2. Then mmapped that address using `/dev/mem`, using the hint from [Accessing uncachable region using mmap and /proc/mtrr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26825420/accessing-uncachable-region-using-mmap-and-proc-mtrr)
3. Make a pointer of my structure and assign that `mmaped` pointer to my structure pointer.

My code is :

```
#define MTRR_BASE 0xf80000
#define MTRR_SIZE 0x40000
#define MTRR_TYPE "write-back"
#define KEY_LEN 128
#define ERRSTRING strerror (errno)


static struct CACHE_ENV{
    unsigned char in[KEY_LEN];
    unsigned char out[KEY_LEN];
}cacheEnv;


static char *mtrr_strings[MTRR_NUM_TYPES] =
    {
            "uncachable",               /* 0 */
            "write-combining",          /* 1 */
            "?",                        /* 2 */
            "?",                        /* 3 */
            "write-through",            /* 4 */
            "write-protect",            /* 5 */
            "write-back",               /* 6 */
    };


int mtrr_mmap(){

    int fd;
    fd = open("/dev/mem", O_RDWR|O_SYNC);
    if (fd == -1) {
        printf("\n Error opening /dev/mem");
        return 0;
    }

 
    unsigned char *addr = (unsigned char*)mmap((void *)MTRR_BASE, MTRR_SIZE, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE, fd, 0x0);

    if (addr == MAP_FAILED) {
        printf("\n mmap() failed");
    }

    struct CACHE_ENV *enc_str =(struct CACHE_ENV *) addr;

    printf("size of enc_str is %ld\n", sizeof (*enc_str));

    // will read 64 bytes at a time from *enc_str to load struct CACHE_ENV into L1d cache 
    /**

    */


   // unmmap
   if (munmap(addr, MTRR_SIZE) == -1) {
       printf("\n Unmapping failed");
       return 0;
   }
   printf("\n Success......\n");
   return 0;
}


void mtrr_add(){
   int fd;
   struct mtrr_sentry sentry;
   sentry.base = MTRR_BASE;
   sentry.size = MTRR_SIZE;

   for (sentry.type = 0; sentry.type < MTRR_NUM_TYPES; ++sentry.type){
       if (strcmp (MTRR_TYPE, mtrr_strings[sentry.type]) == 0) break;
   }

   if (sentry.type >= MTRR_NUM_TYPES){
       fprintf (stderr, "Illegal type: \"%s\"\n", MTRR_TYPE);
       exit (2);
   }

   if ( ( fd = open ("/proc/mtrr", O_WRONLY, 0) ) == -1 ){
      if (errno == ENOENT){
          fputs ("/proc/mtrr not found: not supported or you don't have a PPro?\n",
               stderr);
          exit (3);
      }
      fprintf (stderr, "Error opening /proc/mtrr\t%s\n", ERRSTRING);
      exit (4);
   }

   // adding MTRR entry
   if (ioctl (fd, MTRRIOC_ADD_ENTRY, &sentry) == -1){
      fprintf (stderr, "Error doing ioctl(2) on /dev/mtrr\t%s\n", ERRSTRING);
      exit (5);
   }

   // call memory map
   mtrr_mmap();

   fprintf (stderr, "Sleeping for 15 seconds so you can see the new entry\n");
   sleep (15);
   close (fd);
   fputs ("I've just closed /proc/mtrr so now the new entry should be gone\n", stderr);
}


int main (){
   mtrr_add();
}
```

This code compiles and runs. After running the code, `cat /proc/mtrr` shows,

```
reg00: base=0x080000000 ( 2048MB), size= 2048MB, count=1: uncachable
reg01: base=0x070000000 ( 1792MB), size=  256MB, count=1: uncachable
. 
reg06: base=0x000f80000 (   15MB), size=  256KB, count=1: write-back
```

The above output shows that a new `/proc/mtrr` entry of the desired type is created. As my structure size is 256B, it should fit into L1d cache.

However, I'm confused, if this code is doing what I'm trying to achieve, as I do not know how to verify if my structure is in the L1d cache. So, my question is,

- can I use MTRR as I use in `mtrr_add()` to declare a memory range of a particular type and then assign a structure to that memory range?
- Is this `struct CACHE_ENV *enc_str =(struct CACHE_ENV *) addr;` correct way to point to a particular address? I mean, if I assign a value like `enc_str->out = "abcd"` , will it end up in the `addr`?

If you have any suggestions on how to achieve my goal or If I'm doing anything wrong, please let me know.

Comment: I don't think I understand what your goal really is.  AFAIK the MTRRs only determine whether a given region of address space *can* be cached, not whether it actually is at any given moment.  The CPU may read / write / drop cache lines of its own accord at any time.  There is no real way to "verify" that something is in cache as this information would be out of date as soon as you checked it.  Things like side-channel attacks usually just rely on timing how long it takes to load from that address.

Comment: If you want to *encourage* the CPU to have an object in L1 cache at a particular time, for performance, then normally you do this with prefetch instructions or intrinsics.  There are no guarantees that it'll be there, nor would you normally need any such guarantees.

Comment: @NateEldredge, `If you want to encourage the CPU to have an object in L1 cache at a particular time`, yes. This is my goal. I did not know about the `prefetch instructions or intrinsics` until now. From the [MEMORY CACHE CONTROL](https://xem.github.io/minix86/manual/intel-x86-and-64-manual-vol3/o_fe12b1e2a880e0ce-419.html), I understand that, if a memory address is a write-back type a `write-miss` will cause a cache line fill up. Therefore, as at the beginning, my structure is not in the cache, reading and writing 1 byte from the structure will eventually load the structure into the cache.

Comment: @NateEldredge I'm not sure if my understanding is correct or not.

Comment: Well yes, that's how write-back caching works.  But (1) AFAIK write-back is already the default for ordinary memory on x86, so there's no need to mess with MTRRs.  (2) The read miss would already fill the cache line, so the following write is unnecessary.  (3) Actually reading the memory is not the best way to trigger a cache fill, as the CPU thinks you actually need the data and might stall subsequent instructions until it is ready.  That's what prefetching is for; it happens "in the background" so other instructions that don't need the memory can be executed in the meantime.

Comment: (4) If I read the code correctly, your mapping of `/dev/mem` is causing you to write your structure at *physical* address 0.  That can't possibly be a good idea.  You have no idea what kind of important data might be there, or even perhaps memory-mapped I/O.  If you're lucky, you'll *only* hard-crash your system; if unlucky, you might irreparably corrupt your disks too.

Comment: It seems to me you are doing something much more complicated than needed.  It should suffice to just define your struct as an ordinary C variable (`static` or `malloc` or whatever you find best), align it to a cache line with `__attribute__((aligned))` and then prefetch it shortly before you need it.  gcc's `__builtin_prefetch()` is convenient, see https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Other-Builtins.html.  You'll call it several times, once for each cache line that your structure spans.  But none of the stuff with MTRRs or `mmap` or `/dev/mem` should be necessary (or even helpful) at all

Comment: @NateEldredge Thank you.